# Delayed Message Queue Best Practice

Tags: jms

I'm looking into a message queue solution where some messages need to be delivered without delay, and other messages need to be delivered at a specified time.  The delay is anywhere from hours to a week or two.  I have access to a JMS message Queue, but I'm questioning whether it is a good idea to put messages on the queue with long delays.

Is delaying messages a common practice?

Is using the QueueBrowser to peek at the messages and cherry picking the messages at the right time a viable solution (assuming the message as the delivery date in it)?

Is there another solution (other than putting the messages in the database with a time stamp) and periodically querying the database?

Comment: So you're saying you're putting them on the message queue and telling the processor not to process them until the time comes or that you don't add them to the queue until the specific time?

Comment: They're added to the queue, but don't want them processed until some specified time later.

Comment: Also, the delayed message should not block other messages with from being processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS 2.0 supports message delaying; see the spec, section 7.9: You can call `setDeliveryDelay` on the `JMSProducer` with the number of milliseconds you want messages to be delayed. (Note that, confusing as it is, you can *not* use the `setJMSDeliveryTime` method on the Message object.) In JMS 1.1, some JMS implementations support proprietary headers for the same effect.

It's a quite common practice, but it has a major drawback in practical use, when the delay is longer: There's no (standardized) way to access the delayed messages: The `QueueBrowser` doesn't return them until their time has come. If you need more control, you're better off with polling a database.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Though, I wonder if it introduces too much state logic into the broker?  Just because something is allowed, doesn't mean that it is a good idea.  Though, storing the queue in a DB with a time stamp doesn't seem like a good solution either.

Comment: @Thor: Either you let the broker handle the delay, or you do it yourself. If your broker has *really* good tooling, go for that. If not, operating on an SQL database is not that bad, actually :)

And if you like my reply, you can mark it as correct answer ;)